# What does it mean by " item=infix_exp[i++]; " in the following C code?

Tags: c, arrays, postfix-notation, infix-notation

What does it mean by `item=infix_exp[i++];` in the following C code? Line no 21. It is for infix to postfix conversion. As far as I know, here `i` is array index. But why is it incrementing without any loop?

This is the Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int top = -1;
char stack[SIZE];
void push(char item);
char pop();
int is_operator(char symbol);
int precedence(char symbol);
void main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char infix_exp[SIZE], postfix_exp[SIZE];
    char item;
    char x;
    printf("\nEnter Infix expression in parentheses: \n");
    gets(infix_exp);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    item=infix_exp[i++]; /* HERE */
    while(item != '\0')
    {
        if(item == '(')
        {
            push(item);
        }
        else if((item >= 'A'  && item <= 'Z') ||
                (item >= 'a' && item <= 'z'))
        {
            postfix_exp[j++] = item;
        }
        else if(is_operator(item) == 1)
        {
            x=pop();
            while(is_operator(x) == 1 && precedence(x)
                  >= precedence(item))
            {
                postfix_exp[j++] = x;
                x = pop();
            }
            push(x);
            push(item);
        }
        else if(item == ')')
        {
            x = pop();
            while(x != '(')
            {
                postfix_exp[j++] = x;
                x = pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid Arithmetic Expression.\n");
            getch();
        }
        item = infix_exp[i++];
    }
    postfix_exp[j++] = '\0';
    printf("\nArithmetic expression in Postfix notation: ");
    puts(postfix_exp);
    getch();
}
void push(char item)
{
    if(top >= SIZE-1)
    {
        printf("\nStack Overflow. Push not possible.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        top = top+1;
        stack[top] = item;
    }
}
char pop()
{
    char item = NULL;
    if(top <= -1)
    {
        printf("\nStack Underflow. Pop not possible.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        item = stack[top];
        stack[top] = NULL;
        top = top-1;
    }
    return(item);
}
int is_operator(char symbol)
{
    if(symbol == '^' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || 
       symbol == '+' || symbol == '-')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int precedence(char symbol)
{
    if(symbol == '^')
    {
        return(3);
    }
    else if(symbol == '*' || symbol == '/')
    {
        return(2);
    }
    else if(symbol == '+' || symbol == '-')
    {
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`item=infix_exp[i++];` means to fetch `i`th element of the array to `item`, then increment `i` by 1.

It seems the line is there because the author of the code prefered to write `item=infix_exp[i++];` twice (the another one is in line 59) to using `while((item=infix_exp[i++]) != '\0')`.

Answer (score 1):

`item=infix_exp[i++];` is equivalent to

```
item=infix_exp[i];
i++;
```

except that latter has one more [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Answer (score 1):

It is just the same as

```
item=infix_exp[i];
i = i + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement where you are getting confused is

`item=infix_exp[i++]`

Before this line of statement if the value of `i` is `0` then in this line the value of `i` is also `0` but the value of `i` in the next line is `1`. 
This statement is not in loop but the value of `i` is used in a loop. Each time the loop iterates the value of `i` is increased by one. Besides, `i++` has no relation with `loop`. If you want to make the effect of increment in the very next line then you can do so.